# Acceder a un array de objetos

Tags: php

¿Cual seria la sintaxis para poder acceder a esta respuesta hecha con `var_dump`?. Por ejemplo acceder a **EmailAddress**

```
object(stdClass)[5]
  public 'Results' => 
    array (size=50)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'EmailAddress' => string 'a.caminati@fumaiolo.com' (length=23)
          public 'ListID' => string '9c2fa2e06bc24ad62e054484f8894b9f' (length=32)
          public 'Date' => string '2018-09-27 08:45:00' (length=19)
          public 'IPAddress' => string '176.200.55.211' (length=14)
          public 'Latitude' => float 44.417496
          public 'Longitude' => float 12.201096
          public 'City' => string 'Ravenna' (length=7)
          public 'Region' => string 'Emilia-Romagna' (length=14)
          public 'CountryCode' => string 'IT' (length=2)
          public 'CountryName' => string 'Italy' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente colocando `->`, imaginate que tiene un foreach y al recorrelo quieres obtener el valor que es un objeto, bueno lo haces asi:

```
foreach($datos as $dato){

  echo $dato->EmailAddress;

}
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: hola, en estos momentos lo voy a chequear, que sera mas facil de manejar? haciendo un json_encode?

Comment: si un json_encode estaria bien

Comment: hola, lo coloque de esta manera     foreach($result as $dato){
        echo $dato->EmailAddress;
      } y me retorno este error  Undefined property: stdClass::$EmailAddress

Comment: OK dale un print_r($dato) dentro del foreach y me dices que te dice

Answer (score 1):

En el mismo `var_dump` te está indicando que es un objeto, por lo cual debe ser tratado como tal.

```
$variableQueHizoVarDump->Results[{indice}]->{TuCampo};
```

Si te das cuenta a Results se accede con indices porque te está mencionando que es un array.

Comment: hola, en estos momentos lo voy a chequear, que sera mas facil de manejar? haciendo un json_encode?

Comment: hola, lo coloque de esta manera y no funciono $result->Results[{0}]->{EmailAddress}; me retorno este error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']'

Comment: el {} era para indicar que es una variable que puede variar, tiene que quedar así $result->Results[0]->EmalAddress

Answer (score 0):

Saludos a todos y gracias por la ayuda. La respuesta correcta es esta, ya que a donde quiero acceder es objeto->array->objeto

```
echo $result->response->Results[0]->EmailAddress
```

Y para recorrerlo:

```
foreach($result->response->Results as $item){
echo $item->EmailAddress;
}
```